# AWS ec2 instance not open from some ip

Tags: php, apache, magento, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am facing  an issue with Aws  EC2 system. Suddenly it not open from some ip

**Info1:** `EC2 as hosting and select Ubuntu 14 as OS and install Apache PHP`.

**Info2:** `Rds as mysql database instance.`

**issue:**

```
But Suddenly , it not opening from some ips. It SFTP Access is not working  
and it show connection time out. Also it site not opening from some iP
```

Can may one tell what is the issue?

Edit:
Inbound setting:
[image]

Out bound:

[image]

Comment: have you checked your instance security groups, you need to open certain ports to all or specific IP ranges ? you might also need to look at your configs such as bind addresses etc

Comment: is to check at inbounce or out bounce?

Comment: inbound and outbound you mean and yes, so take a look the ports you have open and the access they have. then also check your mysql my.cnf for your bind address and any other configs you need to connect from a remote address.

Comment: if you want to connect to your database you need to open your inbound 3306 port to any source or your ip range.

Comment: Same for any other service you want to use. but changing the port to whatever the service uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look if the 22 port (for SFTP) accepts connection from you IP in the security group:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html

Comment: check my attached picture

Comment: suggest me from picture

Comment: OK, all your ports are open, so this is not the problem.

By default you can only access the cloud by using a SSH key, is that the case?

Have you ever been able to access by SFTP before?